# Copy a directory in Windows CE with a C# application

Tags: c#, .net, embedded, windows-ce

Because I didn't find a way of creating a batch-script that could copy my directory in Windows CE 7 (.NET Framework 3.5), I've tried to solve this by creating a C# application instead.

I've used VS2008 and set my "Target framework" to .NET Framework 3.5. I've written other applications for CE from this PC so I think the problem is my code.

I found an application that already had what I was looking for, this is how it looks after some modification:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

class DirectoryCopyExample
{ 
static void Main()
{
    DirectoryCopy(@"\Hard Disk2\BootFastBlink", @"\Hard Disk\TwinCAT\3.1", true);
}

private static void DirectoryCopy(
    string sourceDirName, string destDirName, bool copySubDirs)
{
    DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(sourceDirName);
    DirectoryInfo[] dirs = dir.GetDirectories();

    // If the source directory does not exist, throw an exception. 
    if (!dir.Exists)
    {
        throw new DirectoryNotFoundException(
            "Source directory does not exist or could not be found: "
            + sourceDirName);
    }

    // If the destination directory does not exist, create it. 
    if (!Directory.Exists(destDirName))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(destDirName);
    }


    // Get the file contents of the directory to copy.
    FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles();

    foreach (FileInfo file in files)
    {
        // Create the path to the new copy of the file. 
        string temppath = Path.Combine(destDirName, file.Name);

        // Copy the file.
        file.CopyTo(temppath, false);
    }

    // If copySubDirs is true, copy the subdirectories. 
    if (copySubDirs)
    {

        foreach (DirectoryInfo subdir in dirs)
        {
            // Create the subdirectory. 
            string temppath = Path.Combine(destDirName, subdir.Name);

            // Copy the subdirectories.
            DirectoryCopy(subdir.FullName, temppath, copySubDirs);
        }
    }
}
```

}

When I run the .exe file in CE, I get an error:

```
"copyFolderCE.exe DirectoryNotFoundException at System.IO.Directory.InternalGetFileDirectoryNames(String fullPath, Boolean file) at System.IO.DirectoryInfo.GetDirectories".....
```

I think the problem might be that the functions aren't available for CE, or that I'm entering the directory names wrong.

Anyone here who could tell me what I'm doing wrong?
Do I need an SDK?

Thanks in advance.

**TLDR:** I wan't to copy files from a USB stick to the hard disk on Windows CE 7.

Comment: For a start, wrap:    DirectoryInfo[] dirs = dir.GetDirectories(); with a try/catch to get more details.  I'm guessing there's something it doesn't like about your source dir: \Hard Disk2\BootFastBlink

Answer (score 0):

Your code is good. I've tested it in a WEC7 .NET CF 3.5 environment and it works perfectly: I copied a directory and subdirectories from a USB stick into the pc hard disk. 
So this is not a WEC7 or .NET problem.
Most probably your sourceDirName is wrong or you do not have read permission on it: I get the same exception as you when I tried to copy a system directory (Application Data) into the pc hard disk.
Or you do not have permission to write on your destinatio dir.

The @ character is good to avoid escaping the \ and so the following code is good if dir names are correct and you have permissions:

> DirectoryCopy(@"\Hard Disk2\BootFastBlink", @"\Hard Disk\TwinCAT\3.1", true);

Comment: Thank you. I will give it a try when I get a chance.